# Does UnityScript has any specification?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to try to write UnityScript [language support plugin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/01/how-to-write-custom-language-support-plugins/) for JetBrains's ide.
But I cannot find any docs (specification?) for this lang. I know that "UnityScript is a proprietary language, and it doesn't follow any concrete specification"([link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript)).
Ok, but does that mean no docs in free access? Or I'm just cursed by google?

P.S. Some time ago I'm heard that UnityScript inspired by microsoft jscript, but i didn't check this info yet.

Comment: Hi! Did you start the work? I started to think about too, maybe we'll do it together?

Comment: @neciu Hi. I'm just start, and didn't do much. You can join, it will be great. You may find my email at github profile. And this is the repo https://github.com/Light241/jb_unityscript